# Does sheafification preserve sheaves for a different topology?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, sheaf-theory, stacks

Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be two Grothendieck topologies on the same small category $C$, and let $T_3 = T_1 \cup T_2$ (by which I mean the smallest Grothendieck topology on $C$ containing $T_1$ and $T_2$).  If $X$ is a $T_1$-sheaf, is its $T_2$-sheafification still a $T_1$-sheaf (and therefore a $T_3$-sheaf)?

If the answer is "not always," then are there conditions one can impose on $T_1$ and $T_2$ to make it true?  Does it matter if $X$ is already $T_2$-separated?

(I'm really interested in the analogous question for stacks, but I'm guessing the answers will be pretty much the same.)

Comment: Just to make things more concrete, have you tried taking T_1 = the canonical topology and T_2 some topology where Hom(-,u) is not a sheaf and seeing if this gives you a counterexample?  I am still trying to develop a nice collection of examples for this stuff, so I can't pick out anything specific.  I am thinking about it.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/80074/commuting-grothendieck-topologies

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think my answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6592/localizing-model-structures) provides a counterexample: Let C be the category a → b, and consider the topologies T<sub>1</sub> generated by the single covering family {a → b} and T<sub>2</sub> generated by declaring the empty family to be a covering of a.  (Caution: In my other answer I used covariant functors for some reason, so I hope I didn't err in translating the example.)

Note that if I switch T<sub>1</sub> and T<sub>2</sub>, though, the condition you ask for is satisfied, even though neither class of sheaves contains the other.  So there may be some interesting conditions under which it is true.

Comment:  If I have parsed correctly what you say, a T_1-presheaf F is a sheaf if and only if the map F(b) -> F(a) induced by the only nonidentity covering a->b is a bijection, and a T_2-presheaf is always a sheaf, so that T_2-sheafification is just the identity functor. I feel uneasy about the empty family being a covering: it seems to me that the sheaf condition is trivial for such a thing...

Comment: That's what I intended for T_1.  For T_2, the sheaf condition is supposed to say that F(a) is a point.

Comment: If you prefer, we could take C = z -> a -> b, T_1 generated by the covering a -> b, T_2 generated by the covering z -> a.

Comment: Thanks!  Maybe we need some kind of "commutativity" condition for the two topologies.


Comment: @Reid: Your last example is clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: At http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/superextensive+site I attempted to write out a proof that this does hold in one particular case (which happens to be the case I care about).


Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I will answer your question properly. I just tell some facts which might be useful

I know there are following categories equivalence
Qcoh(X),Qcoh(X,t),Qcoh(aX,t)

X is a presheaf
Qcoh(X) is quasi coherent modules on X,t is a grothendieck topology. aX is the sheafification according to topology t of X.

If t is coarser than topology of effective descent, then those three categories are equivalent. Which means Qcoh(X)=Qcoh(X,t1)=Qcoh(X,t2)=Qcoh(aX,t1)=Qcoh(aX,t2) are the same if t1 t2 are coarser than effective descent topology. This fact shows that it is not necessary to consider sheaf but presheaf. Their descent theory can be described by category of quasi coherent sheaves.

Similar results applied to stack. These facts are indicated in Giraud's book,but not wrote it out. They were proved by Orlov in his paper quasi coherent sheaves in commutative and noncommutative geometry and Kontsevich-Rosenberg preprint in MPIM "noncommutative stack"

Comment: This doesn't really look relevant to me.